# DATE_ADD(start_date, INTERVAL 1 DAY) with Kotlin Exposed;

Tags: mysql, kotlin, kotlin-exposed

How to use date functions in kotlin-exposed?

I have to add x days to Column and compare with date.

```
open class DBTable(tableName: String) : Table(tableName) {
    val id = integer("id").autoIncrement().primaryKey()
}
object UserAuthorizationDataTable : DBTable("user_auth_table") {
    ..
    val generatedOn:Column<DateTime> = datetime("generated_on").default(DateTime.now())
}

//Querying

table.select {
(UserAuthorizationDataTable.generatedOn + X Days) lessEq date
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I usually like to do `timestamps` and then compare by `OffsetDateTime`

```kotlin
table.select {
  Tables.createdAt greaterEq OffsetDateTime.now().plusSeconds(300)
}
```